# How do I make one element appear without triggering other elements of the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to make a set of buttons that appear and disappear.

How it is supposed to work:

1. I click on link 1 (link 2 is invisible at this point).
2. link 2 should then appear.

the problem here is there can be multiple elements of the same type with the same classes and I can't figure out how to distinguish between just showing the "link2"
that corresponds to the clicked "link1" without triggering the other "link2".

there is some code showing the progress I have made.

thank you in advance!

```
<style>
    .hideaction{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .showaction{
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".elem_action_showing").click(function(){
        $(".elem_action_hiding").removeClass("hideaction").addClass("showaction");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="elem_card card_set_click" style=" border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="elem_hidden">
            <p class="hideaction elem_action_hiding">%link2%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="elem_showing ">
            <p class="elem_action_showing set_click">%link1%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="elem_card card_set_click" style=" border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="elem_hidden">
            <p class="hideaction elem_action_hiding">%link2%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="elem_showing ">
            <p class="elem_action_showing set_click">%link1%</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The solution should work irregardless of how many ".elem_card" and ".hideaction" elements are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're selecting all `.elem_action_hiding` elements. To fix this use DOM traversal to find only the one which is related to the `.elem_action_showing` which was clicked. Try this:

```js
$(".elem_action_showing").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.elem_showing').prev().find(".elem_action_hiding").toggleClass("hideaction showaction");
});
```

```css
.hideaction {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.showaction {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="elem_card card_set_click" style=" border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="elem_hidden">
    <p class="hideaction elem_action_hiding">%link2%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="elem_showing">
    <p class="elem_action_showing set_click">%link1%</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="elem_card card_set_click" style=" border: 1px solid black">
  <div class="elem_hidden">
    <p class="hideaction elem_action_hiding">%link2%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="elem_showing ">
    <p class="elem_action_showing set_click">%link1%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```